# IntelliJ web service and Java client IllegalArgumentException TestWebService is not an interface

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ 10.0.3

I use the menu option "new web service" and this generates a class file and adds to sun-jaxws.xml - this is fine - it's working.

Now if I try to write a Java client for this web service I get IllegalArgumentException TestWebService is not an interface

Here's my client code:

```
public class WebServiceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost/services/TestWebService?wsdl");
        //1st argument service URI, refer to wsdl document above
        //2nd argument is service name, refer to wsdl document above
        QName qname = new QName("http://ws.mydomain.com/", "TestWebServiceService");

        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

        TestWebService test = service.getPort(TestWebService.class); // fails here

        System.out.println(test.sayHelloWorldFrom("TESTING...."));
    }
}
```

How should I implement this? Should I have an interface and a class?  Is there a good example? Best practice?

this is my endpoint definition in sun-jaxws.xml

```
<endpoint
        name='TestWebService'
        implementation='com.allscripts.ws.TestWebService'
        url-pattern='/services/TestWebService'/>
```

Comment: ... and what happens when you actually make the interface?

Comment: If I write an interface then I need to make a TestWebServiceImpl class but then the web service name changes to TestWebServiceImplService.

Comment: And it works? You can always adjust the names.

Comment: I'm not sure how. I edited the question with the endpoint configuration.  Do I need to put the annotations on both interface and class?

Comment: When I change the endpoint to implementation=TestWebServiceImpl the service name changes as well. I don't understand which settings in the XML to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting messed up because I was trying to use the web service withing my application using the same classpath.  Running a test in a different java project works fine.